# How does the request parameters gets created for GET requests in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

This question is influenced by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377957/1527084) by Balus C on the topic of `f:viewParam` . He writes in his answer that the first thing done by the the following code will "*get the request parameter value by name id*".

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</f:metadata>
```

I understand that this feature is used in conjunction with GET requests but I fail to understand how the request parameter with the name "id" gets created in the very first place ?Also if I understood correctly  "f:viewParam" goes hand in hand with the special `includeViewParams` query parameter for implicit navigation . Which of these two features is actually responsible for creating the request parameter ? Or is it none of these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just part of standard HTTP. To pass a request parameter with name `id`, you'd basically need to have a link like follows

```
/view.xhtml?id=42
```

Such an URL is usually already provided elsewhere in your webapp. E.g.

```
<h:link value="View details of item with ID #{item.id}" outcome="view">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
</h:link>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)